# How can I get my .vimrc to load plugins I keep in the same directory?

Tags: vim

I like to keep my .vimrc in a Dropbox folder, allowing each machine I use to simply set $MYVIMRC to read

```
source C:\Dropbox\.vimrc
```

I'd also like to keep my plugins in a Dropbox folder, more specifically, C:\Dropbox\VimPlugins. I found, on StackOverflow, a solution looking like

```
for f in split(glob(expand('%:p:h') . '\VimPlugins\*.vim)
    exe 'source' f
endfor
```

It doesn't seem to run everytime I start up GVIM (Windows). Am I doing something wrong? Is `runtime` relevant instead of `exe`?

Comment: Use pathogen. The only thing you need to figure out is how to load pathogen. (One of the arguments to pathogen infect is the location of the plugins)

Comment: that should work, I don't know, why it shouldn't run when you start Vim.

Comment: Thanks @FDinoff, I will look at Pathogen.